# Change window status from maximized to restore without moving/resizing the window?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to have finer grained control over my windows maximize/restore behaviour. When I restore I want to position and size the window myself overriding the default windows behaviour where it repositions to the original position.

I currently restore (which moves the window to its original location) and then move it again to the location I want but this results in a jumpy experience. Can I do change window maximize/restore status without moving the window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `GetWindowPlacement`, modify rcNormalPosition, `SetWindowPlacement` and finally `ShowWindow` to restore...